# Check connection to database in a thread

Tags: multithreading, database-connection

How do I check a connection to a database while the login form is showing to the user before showing all tools on the login form?

In an application, I plan to arrange the following steps:
1-Login form without any special tools except a label and background image (similar to a Splash form).
2. Behind the login form (preferably inside a thread) is the connection to the server, and the user sees a label with this text: try to connect to database...
3. If a connection is established (flag == right), a series of tools will be displayed for login user.
4. If the connection to the server is not established (flag == false), a series of other tools will be displayed to user for addressing the server.

I hope I could clearly explain it.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI;
using System.Reflection;
 
public partial class LoginForm : Form
    {
    
        public LoginForm()
        {
            this.DoubleBuffered = true;
            InitializeComponent();
            System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(CheckConnection));
            t.Start();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            t.Abort();
        }
 
 bool flag;
        private void CheckConnection()
        {
           using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection connection =
              new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
                  (connectionString))
            {
                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    connection.Close();
                    flag = true;
                }
                catch
                {
                    flag = false;
                }
            }
        }
 
private void SplashScreenForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (flag)
            {
                //Do somethings to login user
            }
            else
            {
                //Do something to create connection to database
            }
 
        }
```

The problem with this code is that the thread starts running before the form is displayed, and the program initially starts with a delay and immediately all the tools are displayed. Thanks for giving friends guidance.

Answer (score 0):

I used Backgroundworker controller to solve this problem. It works very excellent.
Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=netframework-4.8